# Select second Item in event list

Tags: zapier

I have an trigger that returns a list of items. I want to pass on the first and second to another service.

Example Json:

```
{ "target": [
    { "alternateId": "aaa" },
    { "alternateId": "bbb" },
    { "alternateId": "ccc" }
]}
```

I need `target[0].alternateId` and `target[1].alternateId`.

I have tried **Utilities**: 'Pick from a List', it doesn't let me select the second item. **Code** is oddly worse, it doesn't handle list inputs at all.

Here is screen shot of my **Code**. This works when I test and review, but fails when event Triggers.

[image: A screenshot of my __Code__]
The error I get is that `inputData` is undefined.

The exact error is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`.

Input is shown as `idlist:  {{87487405__target[]alternateId}}`

If I comment out my code, other then the loging. It shows that  `inputData` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Is the data being passed into the Code Step being converted back into an object?

EG -

```
let b = JSON.parse(inputData.input)
return {1: b.items[0], 2: b.items[1]};
```

Comment: Code Step inputData is invalid. `{{ items[ ]id }}`

Comment: @NicholasMarshall Would you be able to send over a screenshot of the Code Step portion of the Zap? I'll need a bit more context to figure this one out.

Comment: Updated Question with screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem, there is a bug with Zapier's Okta integration. Okta Web Hooks return a list of events. Zapier wasn't parsing those correctly.

I switched to using `Webhooks by Zapier - Catch Raw Hook`. Then parse the Json in a Code Action, returning a list of events.